# Function pointers as template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

In the following C++ code, the line `bar<func_ptr>(); //does not work` causes a compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(){
    cout<<"Hello world";
};

template<void(*func)()> 
void bar(){
    (*func)();
}

int main() {
    using fun_ptr_type= void(*)();
    constexpr fun_ptr_type func_ptr=&foo;

    bar<&foo>();     //works
    bar<func_ptr>(); //does not work
    return 0;
}
```

The output of g++ is this:

```
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/main.cpp:19:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘bar()’
  bar<func_ptr>(); //does not work
                ^
src/main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: template<void (* func)()> void bar()
 void bar(){
      ^~~
src/main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
src/main.cpp:19:16: error: ‘(fun_ptr_type)func_ptr’ is not a valid template argument for ty
pe ‘void (*)()’
  bar<func_ptr>(); //does not work
                ^
src/main.cpp:19:16: error: it must be the address of a function with external linkage
```

I do not understand why it works when I directly pass the address of `foo` as a template argument but when I pass the constexpr `func_ptr`, the code does not compile anymore even though it holds exactly that address of `foo` at compilation time. Can someone explain this to me?

EDIT: My g++ version is

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: No repro with gcc8 and clang6.

Comment: Works as expected [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef9bfa4258d80f78) (C++17).

Comment: Got error in C++14 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a22e43946f525d5a)

Comment: I remember some change with regardes to pointers to globals vs constexpr literals as being valid for template parameters since C++11.  But I don't remember if this is one of those cases, nor how to find it.

Comment: Same experience as Jarod42.  C++17 it works; C++14 spits out an error.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I had misunderstood something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters it says:

> For pointers to functions, the valid arguments are pointers to functions with linkage (or **constant expressions that evaluate to null pointer values**). (until C++17).

Since `constexpr fun_ptr_type func_ptr=&foo` does not evaluate to a `nullptr` value at compile time, it fails if you run it with `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++11`.

However C++17 imposes no such requirement on function pointer non type template parameters. It says:

> The template argument that can be used with a non-type template parameter can be **any converted constant expression of the type of the template parameter**. (since C++17)

(There are some exceptions to the above but none apply to function pointers).

So the code you provide runs perfectly with the `-std=c++17` option.